# printing the value and memory location of each character by using two different arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function and inside it two arrays.
In the first loop, I initialize pointers to NULL
In the second loop, I set each pointer to point to one character in the other array. So in pointer array location [0] there is a char pointer that points to character array location [0] etc.
In the third loop, I print out the value and memory location of each character.

However, my code is not working as intended, causing IDE to crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void printName(char *pointer);

    int main (void)
    {
     char *name = "Example";
     printName(*name);    
     return 0;
    }
    void printName(char *pointer)
    {
        char arrayOfChars[10];
        char arrayOfPointers[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
             arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
             arrayOfPointers[i] = &arrayOfChars[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
        {
             printf("Value: %d, addr: %p\n", pointer[i], pointer+i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `printName(*name);` -> `printName(name); `

Comment: and change the second loop to `int i = 0; while( pointer[i] != '\0' ){ arrayOfPointers[i] = &pointer[i]; i++; }` and the third loop to `i = 0; while( pointer[i] != '\0' ){ printf("Value: %d, addr: %p\n", pointer[i], arrayOfPointers[i]); i++; }` oh and also `char arrayOfPointers[10];` - > `char* arrayOfPointers[10];`

Comment: Check your compiler error messages... if there are none then you need to reconfigure the compiler

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors, the first one is pointed by @George in comments:

```
 char *name = "Example";
 printName(*name);    
 return 0;
}

void printName(char *pointer)
```

`printName` is expecting a pointer to `char` but you are passing (due to the dereference `*`) a single `char`, just pass `printName(name);`

And here:

`arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;`

you are assigning a pointer to a `char`

same for

`arrayOfPointers[i] = &arrayOfChars[i];`

If you want an array of pointers (as the comment suggests) use

```
char arrayOfChars[10];
char *arrayOfPointers[10];
```

Also you need to check for the trailing `NUL` character in the loop because you are reading outside of the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

        void printName(char *pointer);

      int main (void)
       {
          char *name = "Example";
           printName(name);
          return 0;
          }
      void printName(char *pointer)
          {
             int i;
         char arrayOfChars[10];
           char arrayOfPointers[10];

            // set values to null
         for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;
             }
           // set each pointer to point to one character in the other array
          for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              {
              arrayOfPointers[i] = &arrayOfChars[i];
            }
                 // print value and memory location:
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
             {
                    printf("Value: %d, addr: %p\n", pointer[i], pointer+i);
              }
            }
```

Just try this code. You are intializing i many times may be that is the error. and also pass name to funtion and not *name because we have to pass the address not the value at that address

Answer (score 0):

Change: printName(*name); to printName(name); because you have already defined it as a pointer array

When you are defining arrayOfPointers, make sure you define it as array of pointers:
char *arrayOfPointers[10];
This is to avoid the conversion error.

Also, if you want to print the char value instead of its ASCII value: change %d  with %c:
printf("Value: %c, addr: %p\n", pointer[i], pointer + i);

NB: Your code uses static array sizes and not dynamic. Because of that, the last three values you will get while printing "Example" addresses will be garbage values.